# validation of f.association in simple_form_for  @form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am a newbie in rails.I have two models:Form and FormType.A form_type can have zero or one form.A form belongs to only one form_type.For this I have created the models as below:

```
 class FormType < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :form
    attr_accessible :name

 end 


 class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :form_type

   validates :name, :presence => true
   validates_presence_of :form_type 

   attr_accessible :name, :enabled

 end
```

my _form.html.erb is as below

```
<%= simple_form_for(@form, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' },
 :url => @form.new_record?() ? admin_forms_path : admin_form_path,
 :method => @form.new_record?() ? 'post':'put' ) do |f| %>
<div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :name, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
      <%= f.association :form_type,:required => true, :hint => "select type" %>
  <%= f.input :enabled %>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
       <%=  f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
       <% if ! @form.new_record?() %>
       <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
           admin_form_path(@form),
          :method => 'delete',
          :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm")),
          :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
       <% end %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

This is my controller code.

```
def create
@form = Form.new
@form.name = params[:form][:name]
@form.enabled = params[:form][:enabled]
@form.form_type_id = params[:form][:form_type_id].to_i
 if @form.save
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
 else
    render action: "new"
 end
```

end

I am able see the serverside valdiation fired for name field but not able to validate association.Can anyone point my mistake or some useful articles to resolve this.

Comment: You need to post your controller code too as their are too many questions such as why are you passing the :url and :method into the simple_form_for method? You should not have to do this and also is your object instance called @business_form or @form? as you have both in the html

Comment: @ADAM i've the controller code now.my object is form not business_form

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because of the way you are assigning the attributes in your create method. The way you are doing is not really standard.

In particular this line is probably the culprit because if you dont pass a value it will be 0, because you are casting the value by calling .to_i . So no matter what the validated_presence_of :form_type becomes useless:

```
@form.form_type_id = params[:form][:form_type_id].to_i
```

ie/ `nil.to_i` is equal to `0` which will pass your validation

try this instead for your create method:

```
def create
    @form = Form.new(params[:form]) #mass assignment
    if @form.save
        redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
        render action: "new"
    end
end
```

In your Form model make sure you have whitelisted the values for which you would like to allow mass assignment. In this case - `attr_accessible :name, :enabled, :form_type_id`

Also in your simple_form_for method in your html file take out the following, as you are duplicating the functionality of rails - it already knows to change the request and correct routes to a post / put based on whether or not the `@form` is a new record or not.

```
:url => @form.new_record?() ? admin_forms_path : admin_form_path,
:method => @form.new_record?() ? 'post':'put'
```

Looks like you have a admin namespace (in an admin folder) - if that is the case use this instead:

```
<%= simple_form_for([:admin, @form]) do |f| %>
```

Also, i dont know much about your app but suspect the has_one :form on the form model should be has_many :forms ?

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks @ADAM for your detailed answer.But I am not able to work it out even when i add the form_type_id to attr_accessible list.Also i am getting the validation msg for the name field instead of select field even though it is filled in the form while submission and the type selectbox is left blank

Comment: in your Form model put `attr_accessible :form_type_id` and try `<%= f.text_field :name %> in your form html instead of f.input :name